# Hidden elements triggered onClick on mobile

Tags: css, mobile, hover, click

I have `div` and inside `button`s. Buttons are hidden (display only when `div` is on hover).

Problem is that on mobile when I hit `div` in place where should be `button` it's triggered.

I only want to display hidden elements on hit (on touch devices) not `button` click effect.

I solved it by change `hover` to `active` class and JS functions:

```js
const btn = document.querySelector('button');

btn.addEventListener('click', function() {
  alert('aaa');
})
```

```css
.first {
  width: 300px;
  height: 300px;
  outline: 1px solid red;
}

.first .second {
  display: none;
  width: 20%;
  height: 20%;
}

.first:focus .second {
  display: block;
}

@media (min-width: 600px) {
  .first:hover .second {
    display: block;
  }
}

.btn {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="first">
  <div class="second">
    <button class="btn">click</button>
  </div>
</div>
```

I am looking for a better solution. Maybe some simpler using only css?

Check on mobile and press top left corner, it trigger function

Comment: please show us also your `html` and `css` code or bether: make a full example with the stackoverflow snippet

Comment: add codepen on my post. It trigger function and next show button